# Composition over Inheritance usage

Tags: java, spring-integration

I was having an argument with a colleague of mine.

Which of the following 2 code snippets feels better to you considering that "composition should be used instead of inheritance"?

1)

```
class JsonToSpecificTransformer implements Transformer {

    private final JsonToObjectTransformer jsonTransformer = Transformers.fromJson(Specific.class);

    @Override
    public Message<?> transform(Message<?> message) {
        return jsonTransformer.transform(message);
    }
}
```

2)

```
class JsonToSpecificTransformer2 extends JsonToObjectTransformer {
    public JsonToSpecificTransformer2() {
        super(Specific.class);
    }
}
```

The specific class would show something like this:

```
@Data
class Specific {
    private int field1;
    ...
}
```

I will comment a little bit about these 2 code snippets:

1) uses composition and keeps and inner object so that it doesn't get reinitialized every time.

2) uses inheritance.

Thanks!

Edit :

I am using a DSL IntegrationFlow something like:

```
@Autowired
private JsonToSpecificTransformer jsonToSpecificTransformer;

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
   return IntegrationFlows.from("myChannel")
      .transform(Transformers.fromJson(service2.Specific.class)
      or
      .transform(jsonToSpecificTransformer)
      ...
}
```

Hope this previous code clarifies a little bit about my intentions.

And trying to summarize :

```
@Bean
public JsonToObjectTransformer jsonToSpecificTransformer() {
   return Transformers.fromJson(Specific.class);
}

---
@Autowired
//@Qualif...
private JsonToObjectTransformer  jsonToSpecificTransformer;

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
   return IntegrationFlows.from("myChannel")
      .transform(jsonToSpecificTransformer)
      ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to extend `JsonToObjectTransformer`? All you're doing is calling the super constructor in `JsonToSpecificTransformer2`, why not use `JsonToObjectTransformer` directly?

Comment: The service1 takes the Specific object and transforms it into the json.
The name of the class and of the jsonType header is service1.Specific.
And then, 
service 2 takes the json and and tries to deserialize it, but uses a jsonType header that exits only in the over service.

So this is why I am not using JsonToObjectTransformer directly and I need to use Transformers.fromJson(service2.Specific);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed. Doesn't look like you should abuse framework classes for this reason. They may change in the future breaking your code.

IMHO no inheritance, no composition at all.

You simply can have a bean like this:

```
@Bean
JsonToObjectTransformer jsonToSpecificTransformer() {
    return Transformers.fromJson(Specific.class);
}
```

And use it as a plain `Transformer` reference whenever you need.
What is good in this that you don't need to have any extra classes to support at all.